# undefined string- react components

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Im building my first web app with gatsby JS and react through a course. I was going well until I was asked to install styled components and then ketp getting throw errors on my localhost. I have upgraded all my package managers and peer dependencies they asked for, and I am stuck! Can anyone please help me?

- Change node version to 10 from 12
- Changed NVM to 8 from 10
- Updated peer dependencies as requested, Gatsby link, React Helmet, styled components
- Added plugins to gatsby.config file
- Changed version of react router dom and yarn
- Changed from Gatsby js version 2, to Gatsby js version 1 still no help.

> JSONStore._this.handleMittEvent
>
> /Users/jane/Desktop/Projects/gatsby/react-app/.cache/json-store.js:40
>
> 37 | }
>
> 38 |
>
> 39 | handleMittEvent = (type, event) => {
>
> > 40 |   this.setState({
>
> 41 |     staticQueryData: getStaticQueryData(),
>
> 42 |     pageQueryData: getPageQueryData(),
>
> 43 |   })
>
> r.
>
> /Users/jane/Desktop/Projects/gatsby/react-app/.cache/socketIo.js:56
>
> 53 |       }
>
> 54 |     }
>
> 55 |     if (msg.type && msg.payload) {
>
> > 56 |       ___emitter.emit(msg.type, msg.payload)
>
> 57 |     }
>
> 58 |   })
>
> 59 | } catch (err) {
>
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `IndexPage`.
>
> 1. List item

`index.js` content:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby'
import Card from '../components/card'

const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <div className="Hero">
      <div className="HeroGroup">
        <h1>Alpha + Omega Digital</h1>
       <p>React</p>
        <Link to="/page-2/">find out more</Link>
        <div className="Logos">
          <img src={require('../images/logo-sketch.png')} width="50"/>
          <img src={require('../images/logo-figma.png')} width="50"/>
          <img src={require('../images/logo-framer.png')} width="50"/>
          <img src={require('../images/logo-react.png')} width="50"/>
          <img src={require('../images/logo-swift.png')} width="50"/>
          <img src={require('../images/logo-studio.png')} width="50"/>
        </div>
        <svg width="100%" height="172" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill="#fff">
       <animate repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="10s"
      values="M0 25.9086C277 84.5821 433 65.736 720 25.9086C934.818 -3.9019 1214.06 -5.23669 1442 8.06597C2079 45.2421 2208 63.5007 2560 25.9088V171.91L0 171.91V25.9086Z;
      
      M0 87.1596C316 87.1597 444 160 884 52.0001C1324 -55.9999 1320.29 34.966 1538 71.251C1814 117.251 2156 189.252 2560 87.1597V233.161L0 233.161V87.1596Z;

      M0 53.6584C158 11.0001 213 0 363 0C513 0 855.555 115.001 1154 115.001C1440 115.001 1626 -38.0004 2560 53.6585V199.66L0 199.66V53.6584Z;

      M0 25.9086C277 84.5821 433 65.736 720 25.9086C934.818 -3.9019 1214.06 -5.23669 1442 8.06597C2079 45.2421 2208 63.5007 2560 25.9088V171.91L0 171.91V25.9086Z
      
      "
      />
        </path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="Cards">
    <h2>See all Projects</h2>
    <div className="CardGroup">
    <Card 
    title="In and Out Fitness"
    text="12 sections"
    image={require('../images/wallpaper.jpg')}/>
    <Card 
    title="Gutter Guard"
    text="12 sections"
    image={require('../images/wallpaper2.jpg')}/>
    <Card 
    title="Mercers restaurant"
    text="12 sections"
    image={require('../images/wallpaper3.jpg')}/>
    <Card 
    title="Eltham Chiro"
    text="12 sections"
    image={require('../images/wallpaper4.jpg')}/>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: Can you show the code for  `IndexPage` ?

Comment: You mean the index.js file in the pages folder? Here it is https://codepen.io/genesis16/project/editor/DBpoQW

Comment: In `'compoents/card' are you` `import logo-sketch from  '../images/logo-sketch.png'` and are you using graphql to static query ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with this line:

```
import Link from 'gatsby'
```

It should be

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
```

It throws the error because Link is not a component.

> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Comment: I change it to {Link} from gatsby and it is still throwing the same JSON store event :(

Comment: @JaneLee oh hhhm it could be a different component inside your index then... have you checked `<Card>`? Make sure it's `export default Card`

Comment: Hey Derek- in card.js yeah it's export default card. This is the repo https://github.com/genesis16/react-app2

Comment: hey @JaneLee so.. I don't see any error at all? Looks like it builds fine